# BennyBox 3D GameEngine Mesh

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, game-engine

I'm using the 3D Game Engine from https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine as a starting point to create a spherical mesh. The goal later on is to be able to control the vertices of that mesh during runtime.

Before proceeding however, I need to make sure I am able to create a mesh proceduraly. There are two ways of getting the mesh into the GameEngine.

- Import an OBJ file. When you run the program, you will notice a Blender Monkey Head with a texture.
- Create an array of vertices, indices (use both of these to create the mesh) and a material. You will notice, that I created a small pyramid behind the Monkey head. To me at least, the pyramid appears to be dark brown. However I applied a similar texture as the one I put on the monkey.

My project is at https://github.com/TomaszNaglik/GameEngine.
Current commit: 77b5495

The game file where I set up the game environment: com.base.game/TestSphere.java
I start building the mesh at line 44:

```
Vertex[] vertices = {   new Vertex(new Vector3f(-1,-1,0), new Vector2f(0,0)),
                            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0,1,0), new Vector2f(0.5f,0)),
                            new Vertex(new Vector3f(1,-1,0), new Vector2f(1.0f,0)),
                            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0,-1,1), new Vector2f(0.5f,1.0f))};

    int[] indices = new int[]   {3,1,0,
                                 2,1,3,
                                 0,1,2,
                                 0,2,3};

    Mesh pyramid = new Mesh(vertices, indices,true);
    Material material = new Material(new Texture("bricks2.jpg"), 1, 8,new Texture("bricks2_normal.png"), new Texture("bricks2_disp.jpg"), 0.04f, -1.0f);

    GameObject myMesh = new GameObject();
    AddObject(myMesh);
    myMesh.AddComponent(new MeshRenderer(pyramid, material)).AddComponent(new Rotate(0.005f));
    myMesh.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(5, 0, 5);
```

As far as I can tell, the problem can either be in the mesh or the material. The mesh is visible, but the texture isn't. the material works on a different imported mesh. I am basically stuck. Any ideas in which direction I could go from here?

Thank you in adavance.

Tomasz Naglik

Comment: My guess is your missing the texture UV coords that are being imported from the .Obj file.  Without them it doesn't know how to properly wrap the texture around the object

Comment: @CraigR8806 he has them in `vertices`

Comment: Vertices defines the coordinates of the meshes vertices, not the texture coords.  For every 3D vertex,  there should be a corresponding 2d coord that corresponds to the texture.  The indices array just is a compression technique, so the same vertex doesn't have to be defined multiple times for triangles that share the same point

Comment: Open up the obj file in a file editor I'll bet you'll see 2d coords

Comment: @CraigR8806 That is how TheBennyBox defined his mesh data structure - UV's and vertex data are coupled 1-to-1

Comment: @meowgoesthedog sorry, I see what you mean now.  I'm not sure what the problem could be then

Comment: Yes, precisely, the UW coordinates are inside the Vertex structure. I Experimented around with them, but the coordinates that you see above are taken directly from TheBennyBox, and they should work. I was thinking perhaps that normals are not set. But I am setting the normals on the mesh with the calcNormals method.

Comment: @TomaszNaglik by "the mesh is visible, but the texture isn't", do you mean that the mesh appears to be flat shaded? Or does it show as a wireframe with no filling? If it's the former then it might be a problem with the texture coordinates - you may have the same coordinate on different vertices on a polygon, which causes a single point on the texture to be stretched. If the latter, then your normals might be wrong and the faces are getting culled.

Comment: I see a dark brown, flat, filled-in pyramid. In the code above you can see the vertecies and their text coordiantes. I played around with the text coordinates, but nothing that I did changed the result. This is why I don't think the textCoordinates are the issue.

Comment: Plus, I also imagine that if it was one pixel being stretched out over the whole mesh, it would still reflect my directional light, and hence would not be so dark anymore. I would put a screenshot of what I am talking about, but I don't see any options do it here. Here is a link to the uploaded picture:https://pasteboard.co/GBwjQHd.png

Comment: It looks like only the ambient light is being applied.

Comment: I'm applying two directional lights that are coming exactly opposite from each other. In the picture under the link you can see an imported model from blender with a texture. https://pasteboard.co/GBxdoej.png

Comment: Have you tried rendering just a basic quad with a texture in 3D space? That is where I would start.

Comment: In fact I started with rendering a triangle. I again played with the textCoordinates but got also a dark brown triangle. The triangle is visible, and is in 3D space. I can even do rotation and translation on the triangle. the case above shows similar results.

Comment: What I also tried is to import a simple triangle from Blender and create my own mesh, and then try to see what the difference is between the output of the object creation that uses the imported mesh and the created mesh. I only saw differences in the vbo and ibo, but I figure that this is to be expected. Applying the material uses the same method wether I use an imported mesh or a procedurally generated one.

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas?